# onActivityResult in Activity group

Tags: android, activitygroup

the on ActivityResult() method,written in a childActivity  never invoked

My TabGrpActivity extends ActivityGroup.

```
public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup
```

{
    private ArrayListmIdList;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(mIdList==null)
        mIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    obj = new ScheduleView();
    startChildActivity("Activity1", new Intent(this,Activity1.class));
}


public void startChildActivity(String Id,Intent intent)
{
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id, 
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    if(window!=null)
    {
        mIdList.add(Id);
        setContentView(window.getDecorView());
    }
}
```

in my Activity1(a child activity) call a another activity using startActivityForresult().. the code is given below.

```
mybund.putString("event", obj_rowitem.getevent());
Intent schedule = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
schedule.putExtras(mybund);
startActivityForResult(schedule, req_code);
```

and i alsow wrote a onActivityResult method in Activity1, the code given below

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

    year = data.getExtras().getInt("year");
    month=data.getExtras().getInt("month");
    date=data.getExtras().getInt("date");
    String getdate=year+"-"+month+"-"+date;
    readschedules(getdate);
    rowitems=getdata(getdate);
    listview.setAdapter(new CustomView(getApplicationContext(), rowitems));

}
```

the one thing is that i call the Activity2 as a simple activity its not a child activity...

here i have the problem is that... after calling the setResult() in the Activity2 where the control will go....

i didnt understand the life cylcle ActivityGroup..

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ActivityGroup` in the first place. It's been replaced with `Fragment`s in API13 and they're available on ealier versions through the support library.

Comment: Fragment... how can i implement it??

Comment: i am using Api level 10..... can i implement Fragment in Api10

Comment: Theres a whole section dedicated to Fragments in the official Android Developers Guide. You can find it over here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Yes, you can implement fragments in older versions (as low as API 4) of Android by using the support library in your project. Read more about it here http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Comment: is fragment is similar to the activity group....

Comment: is there any other solution for this problem.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the activity context instead of the application context, that way it will return the result to the right activity.
So:

```
Intent schedule = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
```

or:

```
Intent schedule = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class)
```

For more info read about the different contexts.